# Set JS variable from Environment Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-data

I've got an EmberJS app that is using Rails as its server.  In my Javascript code, I have a few variables that change depending on the environment the app is in.  For example, if the app is in the development environment I want the JS code to be sending POST requests to localhost:3000, if it is in staging I want it going to staging.domain.com, and if it is in production it should go to domain.com.  Rather than manually changing all of the constant variables before I change environments, what is the best way to set in JS files constants that vary based on the environment?  The reason I need this is because the ember app is communicating with an external server for its POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

Since I guess you are serving the files (including your ember app js files) with rails, one way you could achieve this is simply by injecting a rails env variable into those files, for example by doing something like this in your index.html:

#### index.html.erb

```
...
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window._current_host = "<%= Rails.env['SERVER_NAME'] %>"
<% end %>
...
```

After doing so you can use that global variable `window._current_host` in your javascript code whereever you need to like:

#### app.js

```
...
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var url = window._current_host + '/somepath/...';
    return Ember.$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      return data;
    });
  }
});
...
```

Or even:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  host: window._current_host
});
```

The above is just pseudo code, and there are surely more ways to do jsut the same, but I guess you get the Idea.

Hope it helps.